# Нужно регулярное выражение (подсветка текста в редакторе кода)

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

Я пишу редактор кода для Python. На Python. Да.

У меня есть выражение для поиска и выделения цветом комментариев. Оно работает вроде как и правильно, но когда # оказывается внутри строки, комментарии отображаются не верно, есть ли способ создать правильное регулярное выражение, чтобы всё выглядело хорошо ?

[image: (Справа снизу)]

```
['#.*?$', comments, CodeFieldBGCL]
```

Comment: Во-первых я тройные кавычки не помню, а во-вторых, редактору кода особая регулярка для комментариев не нужна, потому что коммент останется по последней ветви по `|#.*` при токенизации.

Comment: Нет, это не работает. Результат - https://skrinshoter.ru/sNsbLimzmHq?a @Qwertiy

Comment: Ну так потому что токенизация не так должна работать...

Comment: Пофиксил несколько багов в ответе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо делать примерно так (я тут подзабил на многострочные строки, поскольку редактор вряд ли должен на каждое изменение заново всё парсить и стоит их встроить отдельным флагом). Код на питоне взял [отсюда](https://habr.com/ru/companies/vdsina/articles/563432/), и дописал немного в начало, чтобы показать некоторые особенности. Токены подсвечиваются при наведении мыши. Могут быть недоработки, но их можно поправить, если найдутся.

```js
function build(code) {
  var df = document.createDocumentFragment()
  
  for (const line of code.split(/\r?\n/)) {
    line.replace(/((['"])(?:\\.|(?!\\|\2).)*\2)|(\d+\.\d*|\.\d+|\d+)|(\s+)|\b(and|as|assert|break|class|continue|def|del|elif|else|except|False|finally|for|from|global|if|import|in|is|lambda|None|nonlocal|not|or|pass|raise|return|True|try|while|yield)\b|(\/\/=?|[-+*/%&|]=?|[!:=]=|[=:~()\[\]{}.,])|(\w+)|(#.*)|(.*)/g, (match, str, qout, num, spc, key, op, word, comm, ooops) => {
      var span = document.createElement('span')
      span.className = str && 'str' || num && 'num' || spc && 'spc' || key && 'key' || op && 'op' || word && 'word' || comm && 'comm' || ooops && 'ooops'
      span.textContent = match
      df.appendChild(span)
    })
    
    df.append('\n')
  }
  
  return df;
}

document.querySelector('code').append(build(document.querySelector('textarea').value))
```

```css
.str     { color: grey;                        }
.num     { color: orange;                      }
.spc     {                                     }
.key     { color: blue;     font-weight: bold; }
.op      { color: blue;                        }
.word    { color: black;                       }
.comm    { color: green;                       }
.ooops   { color: red;                         }

span:hover { background: antiquewhite; }
```

```html
<pre><code></code></pre>

<textarea hidden readonly>print('Hi! #hi "hi" \' hi \' \\')
n=1
n=+1.
n+=+1.2
if n:=1: ++n
n//=.5

def get_vowels(String):
    return [each for each in String if each in "aeiou"]
get_vowels("animal") # [a, i, a]
get_vowels("sky") # []
get_vowels("football") # [o, o, a]


def capitalize(String):
    return String.title()
capitalize("shop") # [Shop]
capitalize("python programming") # [Python Programming]
capitalize("how are you!") # [How Are You!]


n=5
string="Hello World "
print(string * n)  #Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World


def merge(dic1,dic2):
    dic3=dic1.copy()
    dic3.update(dic2)
    return dic3
dic1={1:"hello", 2:"world"}
dic2={3:"Python", 4:"Programming"}
merge(dic1,dic2) # {1: 'hello', 2: 'world', 3: 'Python', 4: 'Programming'}


import time
start_time= time.time()
def fun():
    a=2
    b=3
    c=a+b
end_time= time.time()
fun()
timetaken = end_time - start_time
print("Your program takes: ", timetaken) # 0.0345


a=3
b=4
a, b = b, a
print(a, b) # a= 4, b =3


def check_duplicate(lst):
    return len(lst) != len(set(lst))
check_duplicate([1,2,3,4,5,4,6]) # True
check_duplicate([1,2,3]) # False
check_duplicate([1,2,3,4,9]) # False


def Filtering(lst):
    return list(filter(None,lst))
lst=[None,1,3,0,"",5,7]
Filtering(lst) #[1, 3, 5, 7]


def ByteSize(string):
    return len(string.encode("utf8"))
ByteSize("Python") #6
ByteSize("Data") #4


import sys
var1="Python"
var2=100
var3=True
print(sys.getsizeof(var1)) #55
print(sys.getsizeof(var2)) #28
print(sys.getsizeof(var3)) #28


from collections import Counter
def anagrams(str1, str2):
    return Counter(str1) == Counter(str2)
anagrams("abc1", "1bac") # True


my_list = ["leaf", "cherry", "fish"]
my_list1 = ["D","C","B","A"]
my_list2 = [1,2,3,4,5]

my_list.sort() # ['cherry', 'fish', 'leaf']
my_list1.sort() # ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
print(sorted(my_list2, reverse=True)) # [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]


orders = {
 'pizza': 200,
 'burger': 56,
 'pepsi': 25,
    'Coffee': 14
}
sorted_dic= sorted(orders.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
print(sorted_dic)  # [('Coffee', 14), ('pepsi', 25), ('burger', 56), ('pizza', 200)]


my_list = ["Python", "JavaScript", "C++", "Java", "C#", "Dart"]
#method 1
print(my_list[-1])  # Dart
#method 2
print(my_list.pop()) # Dart


my_list1=["Python","JavaScript","C++"]
my_list2=["Java", "Flutter", "Swift"]
#example 1
"My favourite Programming Languages are" , ", ".join(my_list1)) # My favourite Programming Languages are Python, JavaScript, C++
print(", ".join(my_list2))  # Java, Flutter, Swift


def palindrome(data):
    return data == data[::-1]
    
palindrome("level") #True
palindrome("madaa") #False


from random import shuffle
my_list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
my_list2=["A","B","C","D"]
shuffle(my_list1) # [4, 6, 1, 3, 2, 5]
shuffle(my_list2) # ['A', 'D', 'B', 'C']


str1 ="Python Programming"
str2 ="IM A PROGRAMMER"
print(str1.upper()) #PYTHON PROGRAMMING
print(str2.lower()) #im a programmer


#example 1
str1 ="Python Programming"
str2 ="I'm a {}".format(str1)   # I'm a Python Programming
#example 2 - another way
str1 ="Python Programming"
str2 =f"I'm a {str1}"    # I'm a Python Programming


programmers = ["I'm an expert Python Programmer",
               "I'm an expert Javascript Programmer",
               "I'm a professional Python Programmer"
               "I'm a beginner C++ Programmer"
]
#method 1
for p in programmers:
    if p.find("Python"):
        print(p)
#method 2
for p in programmers:
    if "Python" in p:
        print(p)


# fastest way
import sys
sys.stdout.write("Call of duty ")
sys.stdout.write("and Black Ops")
# output: Call of duty and Black Ops
#another way but only for python 3
print("Python ", end="")
print("Programming") 
# output: Python Programming


def chunk(my_list, size):
    return [my_list[i:i+size] for i in range(0,len(my_list), size)]
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
chunk(my_list, 2) # [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]</textarea>
```